# How to invoke c# asynchronous method from web page which in loaded in Xamarin.Android WebView?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm building apps for iOS and Android with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms. I followed the [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#consume-the-hybridwebview) docuemnt to make a HybridWebView control and custom renders on different platform projects.

Now, the issue was in the android project. I followed that document to create a 'JavascriptWebViewClient ' and 'JSBridge' class. In 'JSBridge' class, I definded some methods which will be exported to WebView.

For example,

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

        public JSBridge(HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
        {
            hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer>(hybridRenderer);
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("invokeAction")]
        public void InvokeAction(string data)
        {
            HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

            if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
            {
                ((HybridWebView)hybridRenderer.Element).InvokeAction(data);
            }
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("showDialog")]
        public string ShowDialog(string data)
        {

            string ret = "Alert  :" + DateTime.Now;
            
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

It worked well with the above code. But the real scenario, I need to call some asynchronous method from the shared library. Then, I changed the code like the following:

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

        public JSBridge(HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
        {
            hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer>(hybridRenderer);
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("invokeAction")]
        public void InvokeAction(string data)
        {
            HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

            if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
            {
                ((HybridWebView)hybridRenderer.Element).InvokeAction(data);
            }
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("showDialog")]
        public async Task<string> ShowDialog(string data)
        {

            string ret = "Alert  :" + await GetDataAsync();
            
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

With this way, I even cannot build the project successfully.

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Failed to generate Java type for class: Kp.Droid.JSBridge due to System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.Signature..ctor(String name, String signature, String connector, String managedParameters, String outerType, String superCall) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.cs:line 689 at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.Signature..ctor(MethodDefinition method, ExportAttribute export, TypeDefinitionCache cache) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.cs:line 658 at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.AddMethod(MethodDefinition registeredMethod, MethodDefinition implementedMethod) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.cs:line 385 at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaCallableWrapperGenerator..ctor(TypeDefinition type, String outerType, Action`2 log, TypeDefinitionCache cache) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/451/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaCallableWrapperGenerator.cs:line 140
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache) Kp.Android`

Do you know the reason? And my question is how to call asynchronous c# method from web page in WebView?

Comment: I use the code sample in the ms docs and test it with the `JSBridge` class you provided. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/  I got some complier errors but it was not the same with yours. After i upgraded the Xamarin.Forms to 4.8.0.1821, everything would be okay.  Maybe i miss something. Could you provide more details?

Comment: This issue was not related to the version of Xamarin.Forms. It should be the `Task<string>` is not a Java object and the Java code generator has no idea how to handle it. If I have to call asynchronous method in the 'showDialog()', how to relove it?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create the HybridWebView2 and create the `ShowDialog` method.**

```
 public class HybridWebView2 : WebView
{
    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView2),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }


    public void ShowDialog(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

**2. Consume the HybridWebView**

```
   <local:HybridWebView2 x:Name="hybridWebView2" Uri="index.html" />
```

**3.  Register the `ShowDiaplg` action to be invoked from JavaScript**

```
   hybridWebView2.RegisterAction(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", DateTime.Now + "/n" + data, "OK"));
```

**4. Create the custom renderer on Android platform.**

HybridWebViewRenderer2.cs:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView2), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer2))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
public class HybridWebViewRenderer2 : WebViewRenderer
{
    const string JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge2.showDialog(data);}";
    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer2(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            ((HybridWebView2)Element).Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient2(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge2(this), "jsBridge2");
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{((HybridWebView2)Element).Uri}");
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ((HybridWebView2)Element).Cleanup();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
  }
}
```

JavascriptWebViewClient2.cs:

```
public class JavascriptWebViewClient2 : FormsWebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient2(HybridWebViewRenderer2 renderer, string javascript) : base(renderer)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
```

JSBridge2.cs:

```
  public class JSBridge2 : Java.Lang.Object
{
    readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer2> hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public JSBridge2(HybridWebViewRenderer2 hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer2>(hybridRenderer);
    }

   

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export("showDialog")]
    public void ShowDialog(string data)
    {
        HybridWebViewRenderer2 hybridRenderer;

        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
        {
            ((HybridWebView2)hybridRenderer.Element).ShowDialog(data);
        }
        //string ret = "Alert  :" + DateTime.Now;

        //return ret;
    }
}
```

[image]

I followed the code sample in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/

Comment: I need to call asynchronous c# method from javascript on html. `public async Task<string> ShowDialog(string data)`

Comment: The code i provided is used to call  c# method from javascript on html. Have you try the same code with async? Any issue for this?

Comment: Zang `Have you try the same code with async? Any issue for this?` Please check my original question carefully.

Comment: I tested the same code your provided with the sample in the link you provided.